# Pip requirements aren't installing

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I have Python package called **shenko**. Everything works and I have my code up on [my code up on Github](https://github.com/shenko/shenko/blob/master/requirements_dev.txt).

Now my question is after I install my package (`sudo pip install shenko`)
why can't I get **panda3d** to install as well?

After installing my package I execute `pip list` and see **shenko** but not **panda3d**.

I have tried scouring the internet, I know its something simple but im just at my wits end. Any help or suggestions would be amazing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: in setup.py I have also tried to add the 'panda3d->XXX' with no avail

Comment: btw, in the future it would be etter to include an excerpt of the relevant portions of the the pip `requirements` file here, instead of just a link. That way, people can see the problem immediately instead of having to follow a link, and if the link changes in the future, it won't make this post useless to others.

Comment: You seem to expect that pip will automatically install the contents of `requirements_dev.txt` along with the base package.  As far as I am aware, pip does not do this.  (Why did you think it would?)  It's up to you to manually run `pip install -r requirements_dev.txt` afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing dependencies in your requirements_dev.txt requires you to run `pip install -r requirements-dev.txt`. Running `pip install shenko` will not install these.

Instead you should list your package's runtime dependencies in the setup.py as the `install_requires` argument. You've already got this but have a small mistake. In the the code your referenced you need to change:

`install_requires='requirements'` to `install_requires=requirements`

since you are trying to reference a list of requirements. Then add `panda3d` to your existing requirements list.
So it should now look like this:

```
requirements = [
    'Click>=6.0',
    'panda3D==1.10.0',
]
```

Comment: Solved! Tested and confirmed panda3d installs along with my code when I issue 'pip install shenko'. Thanks everybody. Added panda3d requirement to my setup.py as shown in toms code snippet

Comment: @DannyDowshenko Glad its working! If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: you are amazing!